# How do I find the wavefunction equation for a translated potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Let me explain myself. In my case, I know the wavefunction equation of a infinite-U potential which has the form:

$$V(x)=\begin{cases} V_0,\ \ |x|\leq \frac a2\\ \infty, \ \ |x|>\frac a2\end{cases}$$

And I know that after solving the Schrodinger equation the wavefunction is: $$\psi(x)=\sqrt{\frac 2a}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}\left(x-\frac12\right)\right), \ \ \ |x|\leq \frac a2$$ but what if I want, say, the wavefunction of a particle in a potential **slightly** different of the one above, like for example translated to the left: $$V(x)=\begin{cases} V_0,\ \ 0<x<L\\ \infty, \ \ x>L,\ x<0\end{cases}$$ what would be the wavefunction equation? I've seen it's $$\psi(x)=\sqrt{\frac 2L}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)$$ but is there any way of somehow finding the wavefunction equation of *transformed* potential from one that I already know? Or do I just have to do each separately from the beginning?

Comment: *"And I know that after solving the Schrodinger equation the wavefunction is..."* No, this is not true. You've got a typo. You can't subtract $x$ from $1/2$ in the argument of the sine function. $x$ has units of length, but $1/2$ is unitless.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation for $V(x)$, do the substitution:

$$ a \rightarrow a - x_0 $$

Then in $\psi(x)$:

$$ x \rightarrow x_0 $$

Then in the final part:

$$ L \rightarrow a $$
$$ x_0 = \frac 1 2 a $$